# Coordinates on a rotating object

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I am trying to calculate coordinates on a sphere using a raycast and taking the hit.point to get the intersection and then calculate that into latitude and longitude.

The problem I am running into however is that the sphere rotates and hit.point is the global coordinates in unity's environment. So as the sphere turns the hit.point stays the same. How can I account for this rotation to get the right values?

Comment: I don't know much about geometry but you might need some, Like you know the raycast origin position, you know the angle(not sure about this), you know the distance of the raycast. With these information you might calculate the end position of the raycast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the end position. The problem is the sphere can rotate, and because the end point is in universal coordinates the intersection point would be the same if I rotated the sphere 180 degrees, because I did not go to the other side of the sphere but the other side of the sphere came to me.

Comment: Ah now i understand the problem i think. Yes with the fixed position of raycast this aproach seems wrong. Gonna think about it, if i come up with something i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [Transform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html)

```
var sphereTransform = sphereObj.transform;
Vector3 spherePosition = sphereTransform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you have: 1. Calculate the intersection point in object coordinates from the beginning. 2. Transform the intersection point from world to object coordinates afterwards.

### Option 1

Many sphere ray casters already do the calculations in object coordinates (sphere located at the origin...) because it significantly simplifies calculations. You usually know the model transform of the sphere. Just transform your ray with the inverse of this transform and you have the ray expressed in the sphere's object coordinate system. Then do your intersection calculations as before and your result will be in object coordinates again. The key point is that both objects (sphere and ray) have to be in the same coordinate system (either both in object coordinates or both in world coordinates).

### Option 2

The second option is to calculate everything in world coordinates and transform the result back to object coordinates (see Mikko's answer that was just posted while I was writing this).